# Regex validate address string to not contain PO Box patterns

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I'm using `Laravel regex validation` on the address field provided by users.

I found multiple posts that help to validate address string to be a valid PO Box like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680050/po-box-regular-expression-validation) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159535/po-box-validation), but I need to do the opposite and make sure the provided string is not a PO Box.

PS I don't need to do any address validation, just wanna make sure its anything but a PO Box.

I found this rule pretty useful since it checks for po box number to be present

```
/^\s*(.*((p|post)[-.\s]*(o|off|office)[-.\s]*(b|box|bin)[-.\s]*)|.*((p|post)[-.\s]*(o|off|office)[-.\s]*)|.*((p|post)[-.\s]*(b|box|bin)[-.\s]*)|(box|bin)[-.\s]*)(#|n|num|number)?\s*\d+/i
```

Can someone help me to create opposite expression for this one or anything similar?

I suspect I have to use negative lookahead `?!`

Comment: You have it all there. Extract the alternatives, put them into a group `(?:...|...|...|....)`, and put that group into `^(?!.*<group>).*$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you marked this as a duplicate and gave me only a hint, I still wasn't able to solve this since I'm not very good with regular expressions

Comment: I do not think anyone can help you but yourself because [your pattern is not valid](https://regex101.com/r/tOGnZL/1). The hint is sufficient once you know the exact branches in your pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was able to solve this bought can't post the answer due to you marked this as duplicate, I thought this might be useful for someone who might run into the same problem

Comment: Please fix the second regex you tried first in the post, there is a typo somewhere.

Comment: Removed it @WiktorStribiżew since I can't find the place where I copied it from

Comment: Ok, feel free to post your solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved it by using regex `negative lookahead ?!`

```
/^(?!.*(?:(.*((p|post)[-.\s]*(o|off|office)[-.\s]*(box|bin)[-.\s]*)|.*((p |post)[-.\s]*(box|bin)[-.\s]*)))).*$/i
```

This rule does not require po box number to be present.

Those are examples that will pass:

```
        "The Postal Road",
        "Box Hill",
        "123 Some Street",
        "Controller's Office",
        "pollo St.",
        "123 box canyon rd",
        "777 Post Oak Blvd",
        "PSC 477 Box 396",
        "RR 1 Box 1020",
        "Coop services",
        "65 Brook Ave Ste 1P",
        "pacific city",
        "orange county",
        "obox",
        "pbox",
        "party house",
        "p shorty",
        "something pacif pobo",
        "po helpkline box",
        "po ferrirs",
        "panther boxing",
        "box center",
        "post office",
        "Post",
        "porceline"
```

Those will fail the validation

```
        "post office box",
        "POBOX",
        "po box",
        "POBox12234",
        "p o box",
        "P.O.Box",
        "HC73 P.O. Box 217",
        "P O Box125",
        "P. O. Box",
        "P.O. Box 123",
        "P.O. Box",
        "PO Box N",
        "PO Box",
        "PO-Box",
        "POBOX123",
        "Po Box",
        "Post Box 123",
        "Post Office Box 123",
        "Post Office Box",
        "p box",
        "p-o box",
        "p-o-box",
        "p.o box",
        "p.o. box",
        "p.o.-box",
        "po box 123",
        "po box",
        "po-box",
        "pobox",
        "pobox123",
```

Comment: I looked for an hour and found a hundred examples of how to match P.O. Box, but not how to match an address that isn't a P.O. Box.  Your RegEx is just what I needed and it works very well.  THANK YOU!

Comment: How to write this expression in javascript